# Editing a saved value with coffeescript from form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, coffeescript

I'm trying to edit a number on a page based on what the user inputs, but I can't get it to work exactly right. Every time I get one part of it working another part breaks...

I have a form input field like:

```
<input id="timecard_hours" type="number" placeholder="8"/>
```

And underneath it I have something showing the number of hours they already have (I've hard coded it as 5 here but that would normally be a number that will be taken from the database):

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="center" id="new_timecard_hours">5</h1>
  <p class="center">hours so far this week</p>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to get it so that when the user types a number into the input field, that number will be added to the number of hours already showing at the bottom of the page. I also want it so that if they decide they've changed their mind (before submitting the form) and go back to the input field to change the number, the new number will be added to the old "new_timecard_hours" instead of the new one they had already added.

The coffeescript I have so far is like this:

```
 $ ->
   $('#timecard_hours').focus ->
     @previousHoursValue = +($('#timecard_hours').val())

   $('#timecard_hours').bind "keyup", ->
     newHours = +($('#timecard_hours').val())
     totalHours = +($('#new_timecard_hours').val()) + newHours - @previousHoursValue
     $('#new_timecard_hours').html(totalHours)
```

But this is not adding it to the "new_timecard_hours", it's simply replacing it. Any ideas on how I can do this?

While spending hours on this issue I found something that suggested I somehow saved the "new_timecard_hours" with .data then add that to the input field value...I didn't really understand it and came up with something like this:

```
oldHours = $('#new_timecard_hours').data($('#new_timecard_hours').text())
```

but that didn't really seem to do anything...

Any ideas or help would be very very very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so in case anyone else has a similar issue, I found the solution...in the coffeescript, the totolHours should be;

```
totalHours = +($('#new_timecard_hours').text()) + newHours - @previousHours
```

because the new_timecard_hours is being taken from the database, and so is not a .val (which is only from form inputs, if I'm not mistaken).